# "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" when using praw permalink()

Tags: python, praw

I want to use praw to get the link of a reddit post in the sub r/DJBluntztestzone. Here is the code I am having trouble with:

```
for post in reddit.subreddit('DJBluntztestzone').top('all'):
     link = post.permalink()
     print(link)
```

I am getting that TypeError whenever I try to run it. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

you are calling permalink but it is not a function 
you need to use this

```
for post in reddit.subreddit('DJBluntztestzone').top('all'):
     link = post.permalink
     print(link)
```